# django one to one reverse lookup override

Tags: django, django-models, one-to-one, django-managers

Need help with one to one reverse lookup. My models:

```
class User(MarkedAsDeletedMixin):
    fields here

class UserProfile(MarkedAsDeletedMixin):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class MarkedAsDeletedMixin(models.Model):
    marked_as_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.marked_as_deleted = True
        self.save()
```

You can see I'm overriding the `delete` method so when I do `someuser.userprofile.delete()` I just mark the userprofile object as deleted.

The problem comes when I do `someuser.userprofile` after. I get userprofile, because I didn't delete the userprofile, I just marked it as deleted.

In order to get only userprofile objects not marked as deleted, I need to override `User`'s one to one reverse lookup or do something with UserProfile's manager. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, the record exists so overwriting `user.profile` to hide it would make no sense. That would make the code harder to understand.

You could add a method instead:

```
class User(MarkedAsDeletedMixin):
    def get_profile():
        return self.profile if self.profile and not self.profile.marked_as_deleted else None

class UserProfile(MarkedAsDeletedMixin):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")
```

---

This is a one to one relationship and the main entity is the User instance, not the UserProfile instance. In other words, the `user` is what's been used in most of the code. For example, in a view, you use `request.user`.

I'm not sure what a soft-deleted profile implies in your application but let's imagine it means it's not public. In that case I would save this in the `User`:

```
class User(MarkedAsDeletedMixin):
     is_profile_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use a manager, you'd just have to modify `get_queryset`. It's probably best to put this on a Manager for the `MarkedAsDeletedMixin`—which should get inherited by any subclass. Something like this:

```
from django.db import models

class MarkedAsDeletedManager(models.Manager):

    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.filter(marked_as_deleted=False)

class MarkedAsDeletedMixin(models.Model):
    marked_as_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = MarkedAsDeletedManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.marked_as_deleted = True
        self.save()
```